# How does List<T>.Except compare items?

Tags: c#

so working on an issue of comparing 2 different lists of custom objects i came accross an interesting observation.  I had overidden object.Equals() and had the following class:

```
class Item
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    DayOfWeek[] days;

    public overide Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj.GetType == GetType()
            return this.Equals(obj)

        return false;
    }

    public Equals(Item rhs)
    {
        if(this.ID == rhs.ID)
            if(this.Name == rhs.Name)
                if (this.days.OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(rhs.days.OrderBy(i => i)))
                    return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

When using the following code I was not getting the expected results:

```
List<Item> list1 = GetNewListFromDB();
List<Item> list2 = GetNewListFromDB();
//This is in a loop looking for changes to a table
//there is a delay between the list generation in the actual code

foreach(Item i in list1.Except(list2))
{
   //DoStuff
}
```

Until I overode GetHashCode with the following (which I did as a lets throw this against the wall fix) it was looping through all the items in list1.

```
public overide GetHashCode()
{
    int dayHashCode = 0;
    foreach(DayOfWeek d in days)
    {
        dayHashCode = dayHashCode ^ d.GetHashCode();
    }

    return this.ID.GetHashCode() ^ this.Name.GetHashCode() ^ dayHashCode 
}
```

After I overode GetHashCode I was getting the expected results.  I have been looking but cannot find a good explination of how List.Except actually compares the objects in the collection.  I was hoping some one could explain it to a newer programmer.

Comment: It uses a set which first uses `GetHashCode`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8 But [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) mentions it also. Always implement/override both, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Microsoft's recommendation is to override `GetHashCode` whenever you override `Equals`. It's the first bullet point on the Guidelines for Implementing Equals page on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `EqualityComparer.Default` which in turn relies on `IEquatable.Equals` or overriden `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode`. Your code violates the contract of `Equals` since it's inconsistent with `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @CraigW.: it's more than a recommendation -- the compiler will give a warning if you override `Equals` but not `GetHashCode`. And that is why you never ignore a compiler warning. :-)

Comment: Side note: correct answer for title would be - "List.Except does not compare items as there is no such method"... Please consider providing valid names for methods for future questions like [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Note that documentation explicitly call out out that `Except` uses `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of your custom object via [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms224763%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) comparer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Except` places all of the items in the second sequence into a hash-based set, and then goes through the items in the first set adding each one to the set.  Any item from this sequence which didn't already exist in the set when it was added are yielded.

The use of this hash-based set means that the objects need to have a sensible (and consistent) definition of both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` (either on the object itself, or through the `IEqualityComparer` passed through another overload).

Comment: here is the implementation http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ea36e4160d796452

Comment: @capnhector No, it uses both operations, as I explicitly stated in my answer.

Comment: @capnhector No, it uses both.  if it didn't use both, it wouldn't care if the definitions were consistent, it would only need a sensible `GetHashCode` implementation.  As I very specifically said in my answer, it needs to have a sensible definition of both methods.  It needs that because it uses both.  If it didn't need both, it wouldn't need sensible definitions of both.